# Positioning a div to fixed on scroll to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div `scroll-content` that contains another div `fixme` which I want to fix only when the `scroll-content` div is at the top of the screen. If user scrolls past the `scroll-content` div, the `fixme` should disappear. I am using the code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.fixme').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
  
    $('.fixme').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '50%',
      left: '50%',
      display: 'block'
    });
  } else {
  $('.fixme').css({
 
      display: 'none'
    });
  } 
  
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
}

.scroll-content {
  background: black;
  height: 1000px;
}

.fixme {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>

<div class="scroll-content">
<div class="fixme">Scroll here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `position: sticky` for class `scroll-content`?

Comment: Position sticky doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This here is an example that uses position sticky to keep the `.fixme` element inside of the `.scroll-content` element. It probably didn't work before in your own attempt because of jQuery overwriting the `position` property with `fixed`.

I hope that this is the desired effect.
Otherwise let us know so we can help you figure out another solution.

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
}

.scroll-content {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 1000px;
}

.fixme {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: 50%;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="scroll-content">
  <div class="fixme">Scroll here</div>
</div>
```